# CloudBlob.DownloadToStream returns null

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, blob, azure-storage

I'm trying to download a file from cloudBlob via stream. I refer to this article [CloudBlob](http://jeanpaulva.com/category/azure/)

Here is the code to download the blob

```
public Stream DownloadBlobAsStream(CloudStorageAccount account, string blobUri)
{
    Stream mem = new MemoryStream();
    CloudBlobClient blobclient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlockBlob blob = blobclient.GetBlockBlobReference(blobUri);

    if (blob != null)
        blob.DownloadToStream(mem);

    return mem;
}
```

And the code to convert it into byte array

```
    public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

But I always get null value. Below is the content of the streamed file.

[image]

What is wrong with this? Please help.

**EDIT**

Setting the Position to 0 inside `ReadFully` method is not allowed, so I put it inside `DownloadBlobAsStream`

This should work now:

```
public Stream DownloadBlobAsStream(CloudStorageAccount account, string blobUri)
{
    Stream mem = new MemoryStream();
    CloudBlobClient blobclient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlockBlob blob = blobclient.GetBlockBlobReference(blobUri);

    if (blob != null)
        blob.DownloadToStream(mem);
    mem.Position = 0;   
    return mem;
}
```

Comment: There is some misunderstanding on your part as you sure can set Position to 0 @ ReadFully however you need to use "input" object. Object mem is has local scope inside DownloadBlobAsStream() thats why if you want to set mem.Position it must be done in this function however when you call ReadFully() and pass your "Stream" object, you can set its Position to 0 as well, as I shown in my posting. So both are accepted and will work.

Comment: If I set the Position = 0 inside ReadFully, it throws an error "Not Supported", and when I try to look at input property, `CanSeek = false` but your idea helped a lot. :)

Comment: Just to clarify are you getting a null value or an empty byte array? I haven't seen a null value, but have seen an empty byte array in my testing without in some way changing the stream position.

Comment: Worked great for me.  Thanks.

Comment: one note - blob will be not null even when blob does not exist. Use blockBlob.Exists() instead of (blob != null)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is that your input stream pointer is set to end of the steam (See the screen shot, Length and Position both shows same value) that's why when you read it you always get null. You would need to set to input stream pointer to 0 using **Stream.Position = 0** as below:

```
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

    input.Position = 0; // Add this line to set the input stream position to 0

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: So does this imply that DownloadToStream doesn't actually live up to it's promise? That instead of allowing a user to truly stream the data out of azure that's just doing nearly the same thing as DownloadByteArray as it's forcing you to read the entire file into memory?

Comment: I think CloudBlockBlob.OpenRead() can be used to get a stream that can be used to access parts of the blob without having to download the whole thing first.

Answer (score 10):

How about using the OpenRead() method on the CloudBlob object?

```
public static string ReadFully(string blobUri, string itemUri)
{
    // e.g. itemUri == "foo.txt"
    //   if there is a folder "bar" with foo.txt, provide instead: "bar/foo.txt"
    CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(blobUri));
    CloudBlob blobReference = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlobReference(itemUri);

    using (var stream = blobReference.OpenRead())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried implementing the code above, but to my suprise, the function `GetBlockBlobReference` was not present in `CloudBlobClient` but in `CloudBlockBlob`.

Maybe the DLLs changed through time.

Therefore I present you with my adaptation:

```
public class BlobStorageHelper
{
    private readonly CloudBlobClient _blobClient;
    protected readonly CloudStorageAccount StorageAccount;
    public string _containerName { get; set; }

    public BlobStorageHelper()

    {
        _blobClient = base.StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        _containerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageContainerName"];
        StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"]);
    }

    protected Stream DownloadBlobAsStream(string blobUri)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount account = this.StorageAccount;
        CloudBlockBlob blob = GetBlockBlobReference(account, blobUri);

        Stream mem = new MemoryStream();
        if (blob != null)
        {
            blob.DownloadToStream(mem);                
        }

        return mem;
    }

    private CloudBlockBlob GetBlockBlobReference(CloudStorageAccount account, string blobUri)
    {
        string blobName = blobUri.Substring(blobUri.IndexOf("/" + _containerName + "/")).Replace("/" + _containerName + "/", "");
        CloudBlobClient blobclient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(_containerName);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
        return blob;
    }


    public byte[] DownloadBlobAsByeArray(string blobUri)
    {
        Stream inputStream = DownloadBlobAsStream(blobUri);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

        inputStream.Position = 0; // Add this line to set the input stream position to 0

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }


}
```