# Correct if my understanding on FileStream is Correct

Tags: azure, stream, blob

When I try to read the File from HD

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
if (fi.Exists)
    FileStream stream = fi.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

When I check my stream.Position and stream.Length they both are the same. In general, I expect stream.Position should be zero. Since I haven't read the content in stream.

But I could see the stream.Position has last position in stream. Since there is no difference between Position and Length, when I try to upload a file into BLOB using UploadFromStream(stream) it is failing. Of course, I had another workaround to make the code working. But I'm about above question why I have to reset the position to upload file into BLOB.

Comment: Could you post the code you're using between opening the stream and calling UploadFromStream?

Answer (score 0):

The default FileStream behavior is that stream.position will be set to 0 unless you have read the content. If you just take your code only to test and you will see the stream.position is set to 0 however the stream.length = 0xLENGTH. I have just tested your code as below and I could see exact same results.

```
 string filename = @"c:\2012\Procmon.exe";
 FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);
 FileStream stream = fi.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

I have had similar incident when you are passing stream as parameter to a function and in that case the stream position is set all the way to stream length which is pretty much similar to your case. This [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891857/cloudblob-downloadtostream-returns-null/10892587#10892587) talks about the similar scenario as yours.