# Cannot download blob storage file to memory stream

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download a file from blob storage into the stream. This code below does two things: download to a file and download to stream, only the download to file part works.

```
            var connectionString = "..."
            var fileMetaData = await dbService.GetFileMetaDataAsync(fileId);
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(fileMetaData.ProjectCode);
            var blobPath = $"test/test.csv";
            var reference = container.GetBlobReference(blobPath);
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            try
            {

                await reference.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
                await reference.DownloadToFileAsync("C:\\temp\\test.csv", FileMode.Create);
            }
            catch (RequestFailedException)
            {
                logger.LogError($"Cannot download blob at {blobPath}");

                throw;
            }
```

The Memory stream is empty when I try to read from it with a `StreamReader`
I don't really like the idea of downloading to a temporary file and then read it again
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What happens when you try to download to a memory stream? What error or problem do you get?

Comment: `var blobPath = $"test/test.csv}";` typo here, or in your actual code?

Comment: Doe this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891857

Comment: @DStanley There is no error, the memory stream is just empty

Comment: @RonBeyer I corrected the typo but it's not the root problem

Comment: @DStanley yes it solved my problem!. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the method `OpenReadAsync()` solved my problem

```
var stream = await reference.OpenReadAsync();
```

Comment: would casting the result of OpenReadAsync() explicitly to a MemoryStream work ?

Comment: So many solutions mention `DownloadTo` and `DownloadToAsync`, but fail to mention [`OpenReadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.openreadasync) or [`OpenRead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.openread)